# How can I use scroll into view from different/other page with react and redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga, js-scrollintoview

I am somewhat new to frontend development and have just landed my first job in this area. I am working on a site right now built with React and Redux. The issue I am having is on a page which contains of several sections of divs. The buttons in the Navbar uses a React onClick-event to get the id of the section related to the button, and then "Scroll into view" to scroll down to the section. This works fine, though I want to be able to reach the same page and scroll into view from a different page. Here is an example from a Navbar button:

```
<li>
  <FormattedMessage id="section.categories.funny">
    {text => (
        <button
            type="button"
                onClick={e => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                        if (document.getElementById('funny') !== null) {
                            document
                                .getElementById('funny')
                                .scrollIntoView({ block: 'start', behavior: 'smooth' });
                                }
                    }}
                >
            {text}
        </button>
    )}
  </FormattedMessage>
</li>
```

So an example of this would be:
Let's say this page is on: 'url.com/categories'. When I press the button that says "funny" while on this url, the page scroll down to the section with the id of "funny" no problem. But I would also be able to be on an other page - let's say: "url.com/categories/stories" - have the same navbar there, and when I press the button that says "funny" I would like to be redirected to "url.com/categories" and then scrolled down to the "funny"-section.

I hope my question makes sense, and if it doesn't, let me know! English is not my native tongue and the fine art of asking the right questions seems to play a big role in learning how to code. :) As I said I am pretty new to this and haven't work a lot with React or Redux at all. Thank you! /Joel

Comment: do **NOT** use getElementById in react applications, use Ref instead.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I used [React-Router-Hash-Link](https://github.com/rafrex/react-router-hash-link)

```
import { HashLink as Link } from 'react-router-hash-link';

<Link smooth to="/some/path#with-hash-fragment">Link to Hash Fragment</Link>
```

The smooth prop allows the element to be scrolled into.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try!